# Is there any way to create user login for single project in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, pyqgis

Is there any way to create user login for single project in QGIS? I want to track changes on database when users update features. I know that I can do this on database level but is there way to do this from project level?

Comment: You have a [tag:postgis] tag but are you using PostGIS?  If so, I think it is best to mention that in the body of your question.

Comment: You would be better off creating a specific user at the database level and using this user to connect from QGIS. You can use triggers (and other) mechanisms to track changes and this is what databases are designed to do. This is not what QGIS is best for.

Comment: Seeing the Python tag I would suggest you also look into psycopg2.